# Can I control the order of overlay in Filling?

Tags: plotting, graphics

The default ordering is "in the y direction". In this example I would like the red regions to overlay the blue regions.

```
    Plot[{0, 0.6 a, a, 0.4 + 0.6 a, 0.6 (1 - a), 1 - a, 1 - 0.6 a, 1}, {a,0, 1}, Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, Red}, 3 -> {{4}, Blue}, 5 -> {{6}, Blue},7 -> {{8}, Red}, 1 -> {{2}, Red}}]
```

In my actual code I have a dozen or so regions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is hacky, this might not work in your real case, but you could switch positions of polygons that are red/blue when, blue is in front of red. You have to repeat the replacement until there is no change

```
gr = Plot[{0, 0.6 a, a, 0.4 + 0.6 a, 0.6 (1 - a), 1 - a, 1 - 0.6 a, 1}, 
{a, 0, 1}, 
  Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, Red}, 3 -> {{4}, Blue}, 5 -> {{6}, Blue}, 
    7 -> {{8}, Red}, 1 -> {{2}, Red}}];

gr //. {start__, blue : {EdgeForm[], RGBColor[0, 0, 1], __}, {} ..., 
   red : {EdgeForm[], RGBColor[1, 0, 0], __}, end__} :> {start, red, blue, end}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Edit

Let me elaborate a bit. First, I think I reordered your colors the wrong way. You said "the red regions [should] overlay the blue regions" which I'm doing the other way around.

Additionally, I only gave an example when there is `Blue` as only other color. Probably, you have many different colors. So here is a version that does it correctly and can handle different colors

```
gr = Plot[{0, 0.6 a, a, 0.4 + 0.6 a, 0.6 (1 - a), 1 - a, 1 - 0.6 a, 
   1}, {a, 0, 1}, 
  Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, Red}, 3 -> {{4}, Green}, 5 -> {{6}, Blue}, 
    7 -> {{8}, Red}, 1 -> {{2}, Red}}];
gr //. {start__, red : {EdgeForm[], RGBColor[1, 0, 0], __}, {} ..., 
   other : {EdgeForm[], Except[RGBColor[1, 0, 0], RGBColor[__]], __}, 
   end__} :> {start, other, red, end}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The trick is to use a pattern `Except[RGBColor[1, 0, 0], RGBColor[__]]` that matches all colors except of `Red`.

You see that in the image above there are only the *faces* of the polygons corrected. The lines are still drawn. You can fix this too by simply investigating in the structure of your plot. Therefore, take a look at `InputForm[gr]` and scroll past all the coordinates.

What you will find is exactly the structure I used where every surface is represented as a list `{EdgeForm[], RGBColor...}`. I did nothing more that to look at this and to create a rule that does the transformation you wanted.

Comment: Thanks for your speed of response, halirutan, but I am not expert enough to understand your solution (though I have nothing against "hacky"). And, in my case the regions are not "polygons" because the lines are really polynomial rather than linear.

Comment: A few minutes later! Your solution seems to work, provided I switch red and blue in your code, even when my lines are polynomial. I would need to understand the syntax and logic of your hack to see if I can apply it to my rather more complicated diagram which has around 6 colours, a dozen lines and about 20 regions. Can you instruct me, please?

Comment: @MikeP Please look at the edit of my answer. With this, you don't need to do it for every color, because the rule just pushes red to the background, no matter what other colors you have there..

Comment: Just one more problem! I use some fillings like "Opacity[0.5, RGBColor[1., 0.9, 0.9]]" called say "mycolor". Is there a way of matching such forms, maybe by saying it is equal to or unequal to "mycolor" such that the script would handle RGBs as well as these?

Comment: @MikeP Yes, of course there is a solution for this. You look at `InputForm[gr]` and check how your `Opacity` call translates into the graphics. You will find, that it is kept exactly as you wrote it. Therefore, you need to match both forms: `Except[RGBColor[1, 0, 0], RGBColor[__] | Opacity[__]]`

Answer (score 4):

It seems those drawn first are placed in the lowest layer, so you just need to re-arrange the order of your functions as following:

```
Plot[{
        a, 0.4 + 0.6 a,
        0.6 (1 - a), 1 - a,
        0, 0.6 a,
        1 - 0.6 a, 1
     }, {a, 0, 1}, 
     Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, Blue}, 3 -> {{4}, Blue},
                5 -> {{6}, Red}, 7 -> {{8}, Red}}
    ]
```

[image: blue-first overlay]

Comment: I had expected that the order of the Filling command controlled the overlay but this does seem not to affect the output. Your suggestion that the order of line plotting is important is very useful. I will try to take advantage of this but I would need to know more as in my case a line may be the border between a region of top priority and one of bottom priority. How do you think the overlay order would work in such a case? Given an ordering of the lines, what would be the overlay order in general for the regions formed? I couldn't find any information on this.

Comment: @MikeP It sounds like a combination optimization problem. Do you have a more realistic example?

Comment: I think your suggestion has solved it, though not as elegantly as I would wish. All I may need to do is to use up to two copies of each line so that I can get the boundaries of the regions defined in the order I want.  
     E.g. Plot[{1, x, 1/2 - x, 3/2 - x, 0, x}, {x, 0, 1}, 
 Filling -> {3 -> {{4}, Green}, 1 -> {{2}, Red}, 5 -> {{6}, Blue}}, 
 PlotRange -> {0, 1}] 
        (Sorry, I haven't figured out formatting yet!)