# Change the Filling order

Tags: plotting, filling

I want to this:

[image]

from this picture ,can find that **"red" in front of "blue"**

My code:

```mathematica
Clear["Global`*"];
(*=== data ===*)
ptdata = {{0, 6}, {0.6, 4}, {1.4, 2.8}};
(*=== define function ===*)
interfun1[x_] := InterpolatingPolynomial[ptdata, x];
interfun2[x_] := interfun1@x - 2;

(*=== plot ===*)
Plot[
 {
  If[x < 1.2, interfun1@x],
  If[x >= 1.2, interfun1@x],
  If[x < 1, interfun2@x],
  If[x >= 1, interfun2@x]
  },
 {x, 0, Pi/2},
 Filling -> {
   2 -> {Top, Directive[Opacity@1, Red]},
   4 -> {Top, Directive[Opacity@0.5, Blue]}
   }
 ]
```

get this

[image]

I use mathematica own tools, I found that the red was covered with blue

[image]

By checking the forums, [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/94287/can-i-control-the-order-of-overlay-in-filling) might be useful, but I can't make sense of it

How can I deal with this problem?

Comment: "change the filling order" - why not change the plotting order, then? `Plot[{If[x < 1, interfun2@x], If[x >= 1, interfun2@x], If[x < 1.2, interfun1@x], If[x >= 1.2, interfun1@x]}, {x, 0, Pi/2}, Filling -> {4 -> {Top, Directive[Opacity@1, Red]}, 2 -> {Top, Directive[Opacity@0.5, Blue]}}]`

Comment: @J.M. This method is feasible and feels good. If I insist on changing the filling order，what should I do？

Comment: Nominally, the filling order is dependent on plotting order; I do not know if it can be decoupled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Plot[{
  interfun1[x]
  , interfun2[x]
  , If[x > 1.2, interfun1[x]]
  , If[1 < x <= 1.2, interfun2[x]]
  , If[1.2 < x, interfun2[x], interfun1[x]]
  }
 , {x, 0, 1.5}
 , Exclusions -> Automatic
 , Filling -> {3 -> {Top, Directive[Red]}, 
   4 -> {Top, Directive[Blue]}, 5 -> {1}}
 , FillingStyle -> {Blue}
 , Background -> Nest[Lighter, Blend[{Green, Yellow}], 4]
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
plt = Plot[...]
plt /. {a__, x : {__, GraphicsGroup[{__Polygon}]}, b__, 
   y : {__, GraphicsGroup[{__Polygon}]}, c__} :> {a, y, b, x, c}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't understand the replacement rule at the end, can you explain it briefly?